# Three.js hide radial segments

Tags: three.js

Is there any way to remove or hide radial segments from ConeBufferGeometry, CylinderBufferGeometry etc ? I'm new to 3D and three.js so I don't really know is it some crucial part of these geometries or I can hide it.

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean? What are the "radial segments"? If you remove the outer surface all you're left with is a disc from the bottom of a cone or 2 discs from the ends of the cylindar.

If you wanted just a disc use a [`CircleBufferGeometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/CircleBufferGeometry). If you wanted the ends gone then **read the docs**. They make it pretty clear there is an option to remove the ends

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/ConeBufferGeometry

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/CylinderBufferGeometry

Otherwise you can make your own [custom geometry](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-custom-buffergeometry.html)